# Solve command code problem with system of equations

Tags: warning-messages, broken-code

This is my original equation

```
f[x_, y_] = (4 x^2 + y^2)*Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
```

So I'm trying to find the partial derivatives w/ respect to $x$ and $y$ and set them equal to $0$ to find the critical points. First I found the partial derivatives.

So this is $f_{x}$

```
 In[4]:= D[f[x, y], {x, 1}]

Out[4]= 8 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x (4 x^2 + y^2)
```

and this is $f_{y}$

```
In[5]:= D[f[x, y], {y, 1}]

Out[5]= 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y (4 x^2 + y^2)
```

and this is where I ran into a problem.  After finding the partial derivatives, you're supposed to set them equal to $0$ and solve for $x$ and $y$, so I tried to do that:

```
Solve[{8 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x (4 x^2 + y^2) == 0, 
  2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y (4 x^2 + y^2) == 0}, {x, y}]
```

This is the display

[image]

So from what I know the only critical points I need are $(0,0),(-1,0), and (1,0)$.  Can you tell me how fix the errors?

Comment: Have you tried substituting your putative solutions into the gradient you originally computed as a check?

Comment: Plotting a function is almost always helpful:  `ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Contours -> 20]` or `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = (4 x^2 + y^2)*Exp[-x^2 - y^2];

der = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]

{8 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) x (4 x^2 + y^2), 
 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y - 2 E^(-x^2 - y^2) y (4 x^2 + y^2)}

solns = Solve[der == 0, {x, y}]
```

[image]

```
(* {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, 
  y -> -1}, {x -> 0, y -> 1}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
der /. solns

{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

Or as suggested in the messages, using [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
solns2 = Solve[der == 0, {x, y}, Method -> Reduce]

(* {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> -1}, {x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, 
  y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}} *)
```

or

```
solns3 = {Reduce[der == 0, {x, y}] // ToRules}

(* {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> -1}, {x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> -1, 
  y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}} *)
```